# Printing to a remote printer from a website

Tags: linux, printing

I would like to be able to print to a number of remote printers from a website.

The website runs on a Linux server, and it is the application within the website that generates the print jobs. The remote printers are located at a number of broadband sites. The printers will be serial receipt printers or USB printers. There will most likely be Windows machines near the printers, so they can be used as a part of the solution.

Assuming I can generate the stream of bytes I want any particular printer to receive on the web server, what would be the best way to get those bytes to the remote printers?

I want this to be a simple and reliable process to the end user (once the printers are set up). I *could* do it through a web browser, delivering a PDF and then printing that through a local driver, but I would like to avoid extra steps for the user. They just click a button on a web page and the printer near to them (or even at another site) should come to life to print the item. In some instances the printer will not have an operator, so it should print fully automatically.

I have heard of node.js being used to manage remote printers at restaurants, printing out orders that people have entered into a website, but I cannot find any information on how this is achieved. It does sound very similar to what we want to do.

Any ideas or suggested approaches appreciated.

-- Jason

Just found this [Remote print module in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155740/remote-print-module-in-java) but I would like to avoid java if possible (just not my skill set) but if it is the best approach..?

Comment: Is a VPN possible? You could simply attach the printer to almost any local PC and share it via SAMBA/CUPS. I'm not sure SO is the best place for this question, but I'm kind of at a loss on figuring out which site would be more appropriate.

Comment: Apologies if SO is the wrong forum - I only asked here because it did come up a lot in my searches, with people asking similar questions.

VPN is a possibility, I guess. I assume once a VPN is set up, it would apply to the whole machine, routing all requests to the remote server. Or can a VPN be sandboxed into one corner of the machine and only get applied to printers in some way?

Comment: I think what I am looking for is a method to link a physical COM port on a Windows machine to a virtual serial (tty) port on the Linux web server. If the Windows machine can be made to connect up the serial port to a remote TCP/IP address and port, then I could probably take it from there.

From a conceptual POV my web processes would print to a local tty port, and that transparently be transferred to COM port (with a printer attached) on a PC possibly on the other side on the country.

Yes, VPN *could* be a part of that, but I don't see how yet.

Comment: I am putting this on the back-burner for now, as the need for it has dropped down my list of priorities. Thanks for the responses - I may well be back to revisit this question in the future.